# Gitlab: Clone uses old name instead of new repo name

Tags: git, gitlab

weeks ago, I set up a repository in our internal gitlab server with the name `thisismyproject`.

After cloning the project into my workbench, the folder `thisismyproject` has been created.
Now, I want to change the name of the repository to camel case, that is, `ThisIsMyProject` - so I did this via `General > Project Name`. That works. However, when I re-clone the repository, the files are still placed inside a folder called `thisismyproject` and not `ThisIsMyProject`.

I know that I could use git clone `gitlab_url/thisismyproject`  `ThisIsMyProject`, but I want this to work automatically.

How can I make the clone command make notice of the changes?

Comment: The default local repo name is from the last segment of the repo URL. As the URL is case-insensitive and is in lower case by default, `git clone` does not know the changes unless you use `gitlab_url/ThisIsMyproject` or `gitlab_url/thisismyproject ThisIsMyProject`.